How to apply blur effect to content under ActionBar in Jetpack Compose?
So far I have a simple Scafold with a transparent ActionBar & StatusBar, and my content scrolls nicely under both bars, including a scrollBehavior to change the top color to a transparent black. Here's the relevant code:
Main Activity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        enableEdgeToEdge()

        ...

Main Composable
...

val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior()
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(currentScreen.route)
            },
            scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                scrolledContainerColor = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.75f),
                navigationIconContentColor = Color.Black,
                titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                actionIconContentColor = Color.Black
            )
        )
    },
) { padding ->
    Box {
        Background()
        MainNavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            navController = navController,
            contentPadding = padding
        )
    }
}

It works and I'm happy with the result, but it'd be great if there was a way to apply a blur effect to the content that gets hidden under the ActionBar, similar to what iOS does natively.
Is there any method to achieve this effect?

Finally, Haze library addressed exactly my scenario.
